# Caml Query Date condition not working

Tags: sharepoint-online, caml-query, caml

In the below query after adding date condition the query returns error - Cannot complete this action. Please try again..

```
    "<View><Query><Where><And><Eq><FieldRef Name='Company' /><Value Type='Text'>" + CompanyName + "</Value></Eq>" +
    "<And><Eq><FieldRef Name='License' /><Value Type='Text'>" + License + "</Value></Eq>" +
    "<And><Eq><FieldRef Name='Active' /><Value Type='Boolean'>0</Value></Eq> <IsNull><FieldRef Name='ReplacementUserID'/></IsNull >" +
    "<And><Geq><FieldRef Name='LicenseExpiryDate'/><Value IncludeTimeValue='FALSE' Type='DateTime'><Now /></Value></Geq>" +
    "</And></And></And></And></Where></Query><RowLimit>100</RowLimit></View>"
```

Comment: I think you should add one more `<And>` before `<IsNull><FieldRef Name='ReplacementUserID'/>` or add closing `</And>` after that condition (as per your requirements/conditions). You are doing it wrong here.

Comment: Hi @GaneshSanap, when i try that i get the following error - One or more field types are not installed properly. Go to the list settings page to delete these fields. The query was working fine before i added the 4th(last) <and></and> tag, ie. for date comparision.

Comment: <And> element can have only two child elements (two conditions). so, you have to change the query accordingly

Comment: The query contains one and max two child elements inside <and> tag.

Comment: Check my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<And>` element can have only two child elements (two conditions). Your query should be in below format:

```
<View>
    <Query>
        <Where>
            <And>
                <Eq><FieldRef Name='Company' /><Value Type='Text'>CompanyName</Value></Eq>
                <And>
                    <Eq><FieldRef Name='License' /><Value Type='Text'>License</Value></Eq>
                    <And>
                        <Eq><FieldRef Name='Active' /><Value Type='Boolean'>0</Value></Eq>
                        <And>
                            <IsNull><FieldRef Name='ReplacementUserID'/></IsNull >
                            <Geq><FieldRef Name='LicenseExpiryDate'/><Value IncludeTimeValue='FALSE' Type='DateTime'><Now /></Value></Geq>
                        </And>
                    </And>
                </And>
            </And>
        </Where>
    </Query>
    <RowLimit>100</RowLimit>
</View>
```

Add variables, `+` and `"` accordingly.

**Documentation**: [CAML Query schema](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/schema/query-schema)

Comment: Same error - Cannot complete this action.

Please try again. I have added variables, + and " accordingly

Comment: What is the data type of `ReplacementUserID`??

Comment: Hi, placing <IsNull></IsNull > after <Geq></Geq> worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Change your caml query to the following, check if it works for you:

```
<Query>
    <Where>
        <And>
            <And>
                <And>
                    <Eq><FieldRef Name='Company' /><Value Type='Text'>" + CompanyName + "</Value></Eq>
                    <Eq><FieldRef Name='License' /><Value Type='Text'>" + License + "</Value></Eq>" +
                "</And>
                <Eq><FieldRef Name='Active' /><Value Type='Boolean'>0</Value></Eq> <IsNull><FieldRef Name='ReplacementUserID'/></IsNull >" +
            "</And>
            <Geq><FieldRef Name='LicenseExpiryDate'/><Value IncludeTimeValue='FALSE' Type='DateTime'><Now /></Value></Geq>" +
        "</And>             
    </Where>
</Query>
```

Comment: Hi @Michael Han_MSFT, The above query returns all data from the list without applying the conditions. Not sure why.